# nginx load balance structure

Tags: nginx, load, load-balancing

I have a website that is growing so my dedicated server can't handle and the lag is real deal. So I decided to try cloud hosting and for this purpose I will use nginx as load balancer.

Qustion 1. 
If I configure the main webserver where domain.tld is located as load balancer like the example [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/loadbalanceexample/) will I be able to use the same server for all my other domains(right now I use normal nginx config to maintan 10 small websites on the same webserver), or the main role will be ONLY to balance and redirect the traffic.

Question 2.
Shall I put copy of the files on the mirror servers ? 
Example : my website is in the http_web folder , where he communicate with MYSQL server. How the requests are handled ? What happens when the balance server redirect the client to the server1 ?

Question 3.
 I plan to start with this structure:
Load balancer (dedicated server) + Mysql -> http servers1, server2,,, on demand3..4..5.. Is that ok?

Answer (score 1):

This diagram should help with how you should set it up. Forgive me if I missed your point to your question. So the green is what is public and red is your private internal network. So your load balancer which you want as nginx has two networks connected to it. Your external public network and your internal network. The lb should handle all the ip's coming from your clients. Then nginx delegates the client to one of the webapps through the private internal network. I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, shall I copy the website's files to all 3 webapp (via rsync?) or the web servers are used ONLY to server requests, that's the point I can't understand.

Comment: Yes each webapp should have everything it needs to run. If you think it is fine to rsync all the files then yes you can. I can't speak for all webapps but you want to have a copy of your website on each one and make sure all of them connect to one database. Nginx basically just passes the request to one of your webapps and then the rest your webapp handles. Hope this makes things more clear. I am happy to explain in a different way if this doesn't make sense.